# Why don't I receive any UDP data?

Tags: python, windows-7, udp

I have a simple Python script which is attempting to listen for any UDP data sent to the wired ethernet adapter (set to a static IP of 10.10.5.51) on my machine:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind(('10.10.5.51', 72))
while True:
    print(s.recvfrom(65535))
```

I can see from wireshark that my machine is receiving data on that port so why isn't the Python script reporting anything?

**Edit1 - testing local addresses**

I tried binding to '127.0.0.1' and sending to the same address with the following sender/receiver and it works...

Sender:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
source_port = 73
dest_port = 72
address = '127.0.0.1'
s.bind((address, source_port))
print("Sending from port: %d"%source_port)
while True:
    print(s.sendto(bytes('Testing..','UTF-8'), (address, dest_port)))
```

Receiver:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
port = 72
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
print("Listening on port: %d"%port)
while True:
    print(s.recvfrom(65535))
```

If I change the address to that of my ethernet card (10.10.5.51) then I see nothing (and wireshark doesn't even show any traffic).

**Edit2 - higher source ports**

If I chance the source port to a non-privileged port (11000 for example), I can now see the traffic my Python sender is producing...

Sender:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
source_port = 11000
dest_port = 72
address = '10.10.20.51'
s.bind((address, source_port))
print("Bound to address: "+address)
print("Sending from port %d to port %d"%(source_port,dest_port))
while True:
    s.sendto(bytes('Testing..','UTF-8'), (address, dest_port))
```

Receiver:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
port = 72
address = '10.10.20.51'
s.bind((address, port))
print("Listening on %s:%d"%(address,port))
while True:
    print(s.recvfrom(65535))
```

...but I'm still not seeing the traffic that wireshark is reporting. Is it possible my Python receiver is somehow binding to the wrong adaptor or something along those lines?

Comment: I don't see the problem but change this s.bind(('10.10.5.51', 72)) to s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 72)) to make sure

Comment: Using '0.0.0.0' didn't work.

Comment: Are you running your code as a privileged user? Low port numbers such as 72 can not usually be opened by a normal user.

Comment: he didn't mention any errors, and hes using windows 7 so there won't be any problems on using low ports.

Comment: Is it possible you have a firewall blocking your application?

Comment: Windows firewall is turned off but in any case, if there was a firewall blocking things, surely wireshark wouldn't be seeing anything?

Comment: no because wireshark will add itself as an exception in the firewall automatically. try sending your own packet to the address and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure do you try with the localhost address "127.0.0.1" or "0.0.0.0"

Comment: Tried both of those to no avail.